# Xorshift random in Java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to implement the [xorshift random number algorithm from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) in Java. It has an example in C that has unsigned longs. Given that Java doesn't have unsigned numbers, how can I get rid of the `Math.abs` in my code below?

I only want positive numbers.

```
private static long x = 0;
private static long y = 0;
private static long z = 0;
private static long w = 0;

private static long xorShiftRandom() {
    while ((x | y | z | w) == 0) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        x = rand.nextLong();
        y = rand.nextLong();
        z = rand.nextLong();
        w = rand.nextLong();
    }
    long t = x ^ (x << 11);
    x = y; 
    y = z;
    z = w;
    return w = Math.abs(w ^ (w >>> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >>> 8)));
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#Example_implementation? If so, that's a **C** example. (Plus it would be nice to link this in your question).

Comment: @John, i only want positive numbers... the shifting produces mostly negative numbers, is there a way to get positive numbers without having to use the abs function?

Comment: @mfc Bit-wise operations have nothing to do with signs. Your problem is actually when showing these values, see my answer.

Comment: Unrelated to your abs() question: while x,y,z,w can't **all** be zero, it's perfectly fine for one or more of them to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no unsigned in Java, so this is not an option. I think that actually your problem is when printing them, they show negative. You can use hexadecimal format (`Long.toHexString()`) to show an *unsigned* value. Or you can use a bigger holder like `BigInteger` to have unsigned decimal representation.

**EDIT**: If `long` in Java spawns from `Long.MIN_VALUE` to `Long.MAX_VALUE`, then a random number generator is expected to generate numbers in the whole domain, not only positive numbers (which is half the domain only).

Comment: There is one operation that *does* care about signs and that is shifting right, which can be done either with sign extension or just on the raw bits as if the number was unsigned. Unsurprisingly, Java offers both the `>>` and the `>>>` operators to cater for that. But that is a bitwise operation that *does* care about signedness, even in Java.

Comment: @Joey Actually, *>>* is bitwise shift and *>>>* is arithmetic shift. So there are no bitwise operations that care about signedness.

Comment: @Kayaman No, they care about sign because of sign extension, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: Oops, I meant that >> is arithmetic shift. >>> was logical shift, not bitwise shift.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your algorithm is entirely wrong. The example from Wikipedia uses 32-bit variables. It is a 128-bit state generator, and the shifts you are using will give a maximal period *ONLY* for such a generator.

The DSI utilities (http://dsiutils.di.unimi.it/) contain several implementation of xorshift*/xorshift+ generators, which are 64-bit variant of xorshift that do not exhibit linear artifacts. I suggest you to start from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the last line of your function to:

```
   w = (w ^ (w >>> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >>> 8)));
   return w & 0x7fffffffffffffffL;
```

This will still generate all 64 bits, but only report 63 of them.

By the way, you shouldn't be potentially spawning a new `Random` object with multiple calls to your method.  Move `Random rand = new Random();` up to where you're declaring `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w`, and make it `private static` as well.  Even though the loop is almost never triggered after the first invocation of your method, it's generally a bad idea to instantiate a PRNG more than once.